# Can macOS Sierra 10.12.6 be used with Xamarin development

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements 
It recommends High Sierra (10.13.x) or higher to do iOS development using Xamarin; my hardware prevents me upgrading to 10.13 so I wonder whether there is any limitation on using macOS 10.12.6 to do iOS development with Xamarin?

Comment: Xamarin iOS relies on the latest XCode tools, which require High Sierra or newer

Comment: XCode 9 works on 10.12.6 ... but no XCode 9.4 for example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The minimum macOS version to run Xcode 9.4.1 (current production release) is

- **10.13.2** (High Sierra)

and that is for iOS development of:

- 11.3
- 11.4

The "soon to be release" iOS 12.0 requires Xcode 10.0 beta 6 and that is tied to a minimum of:

- 10.13.6 (High Sierra)

You could use older Xamarin.iOS releases and target older iOS versions as up to Xcode 9.2 could run on 10.12 (Sierra).

Note: iOS 11.3 has a 12.3% market share and 11.4 has a 62.9% market share, so that is 75% of the current iOS device market.